# Schedule Tasks Windows 7 except on Weekends

Tags: windows-7

Hello I have created windows tasks in the Task Scheduler in Windows 7 that executes batch files. Everything works fine, however I have a problem. I dont want the tasks to run over the weekends. How do I accomplish this?? I dont see any settings in the triggers tab of the task that allows me to do this.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You didn't look hard enough, I guess:

1) Go into Task Mgr:
   My Computer, R-Click, Manage, Scheduled Tasks, [Browse...] to your task

2) R-Click, Properties.  Select [Triggers] tab.

3) Make sure your trigger says "On a schedule"

4) Select "Weekly"

5) From here, you can check any specific day(s) you want it to run.

Simply leave the days you DON'T want it to run unchecked.

Voila.  Done :)